# Converting character to POSIXct in R Markdown is Making Me Sad

Tags: r, posixct

I'm learning to use R as part of a certificate program and I've been trying to compile a report from a practice project in R Markdown and getting my date-times back to POSIXct rather than being characters has been very difficult. I know `write_csv()` saves all cloumns in a dataframe as the character type, and for things like num and Date, I have corrected them using something like:

```
is.factor(all_trips_v2_rmd$date) # this checks to see if the variable is factor-type
all_trips_v2_rmd$date <- as.Date(as.character(all_trips_v2_rmd$date)) # this converts the columns into Date-type
is.Date(all_trips_v2_rmd$date) # this checks to make sure this column is now Date-type
```

which does the job just fine. However, when I run this:

```
is.factor(all_trips_v2_rmd$started_at)
all_trips_v2_rmd$started_at <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(as.character(all_trips_v2_rmd$started_at)), format="%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S")
is.POSIXct(all_trips_v2_rmd$started_at)
```

the output of the first date-time value would be: "2021-04-11 19:00:00." The Y%/m%/d% part of the information will generally be correct, but all H%/M%/S% parts of the data will be exactly 19:00:00. Looking at the character-only version of the .csv file, the first date-time value is: "2021-04-12T18:25:36Z." I've been looking everywhere for a fix, and none of the solutions seem to work.

Comment: There is a colon ":" dividing the time elements and not a slash "/" so the correct  format for  "2021-04-12T18:25:36Z" is "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"

Comment: I think `lubridate` will ease your sadness. Try `all_trips_v2_rmd$started_at = lubridate::ymd_hms(all_trips_v2_rmd$started_at)`.  I tested it with `lubridate::ymd_hms("2021-04-12T18:25:36Z")` and it worked.

Comment: @JonSpring Your answer has eased my sorrows and has converted all the values correctly. I probably should have mentioned at the start my dataframe was about 6,000,000 objects, and the colon divider didn't appear to work for that. I'll try and mark this as the answer, but I don't know if I've unlocked the privileges for that.